# Binding function from other class to Kivy Button

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, pycharm, kivy

[Kivy app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J432.png)
I have 2 .py files in the same project called dailyReports.py and weeklyReports.py and they each generate a different excel sheet, one daily report and the other a weekly report. When I click run, it opens the excel file directly which is what I want.
I am trying to make a simple user-friendly interface that will allow a user to select which report they want to generate and for it to run the according report generator and output the excel file. This is my first time dealing with python and kivy but so far I was able to make my two report generators work and the visual aspect of my kivy GUI is exactly as I want it. My problem is when I try to bind the two buttons in the drop down menu to their according excel generator functions. Could someone please help me? here is my code so far for my .py file containing my kivy code along with a picture of how my current kivy GUI looks like when I click the drop down button.
I would really appreciate it !!!!

```
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
    from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
    from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
    from kivy.config import Config
    from kivy.uix.image import Image
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    dropdown = DropDown()

    class Panel(FloatLayout):

        def __init__(self, **kw):
            super(Panel, self).__init__(**kw)

            # Make the background solid white
            color = Color(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
            self.canvas.add(color)
            rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
            self.canvas.add(rect)

            dropdown = DropDown()

            # Add the label
            label = Label(text="Report Generator", pos_hint={'x': 0, 'y': 0.20}, size_hint=(None, None))
            label.color = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
            label.size_hint = (1, 1)
            label.font_size = 26
            label.bold = True
            self.add_widget(label)

            choice = Button(text="Select Summary Report to Generate", pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .58},
                    size_hint=(0.6, 0.2))
            choice.color = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
            choice.size_hint = (0.45, 0.1)
            choice.font_size = 18
            choice.bold = False
            choice.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)
            self.add_widget(choice)

            btn1 = Button(text='Daily Report', font_size=18, size_hint_y=None, height=60)
            btn1.color = [1, 1, 1, 1]
            btn1.txt= 'Generating Daily Summary Report...'
            btn1.bind(on_release=lambda btn1: dropdown.select(btn1.txt))
            dropdown.add_widget(btn1)
            btn2 = Button(text='Weekly Report', font_size=18, size_hint_y=None, height=60)
            btn2.color = [1, 1, 1, 1]
            btn2.txt = 'Generating Weekly Summary Report...'
            btn2.bind(on_release=lambda btn2: dropdown.select(btn2.txt))
            dropdown.add_widget(btn2)
            dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(choice, 'text', x))


    class Report(App):
       def build(self):[enter image description here][1]
            Config.set('graphics', 'width', '450')
            Config.set('graphics', 'height', '250')
            return Panel(size=(1000,1000))


    # Application Code
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Report().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have add the following code as per snippet. Please refer to the example below for complete details.

## Snippet

```
from DailySummaryReport import DailySummary
from WeeklySummaryReport import WeeklySummary
...
        btn1.bind(on_release=lambda btn1: dropdown.select(btn1.txt))
        btn1.bind(on_release=lambda btn1: DailySummary())
...
        btn2.bind(on_release=lambda btn2: dropdown.select(btn2.txt))
        btn2.bind(on_release=lambda btn2: WeeklySummary())
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from DailySummaryReport import DailySummary
from WeeklySummaryReport import WeeklySummary

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Panel(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Panel, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.size = (1000, 1000)
        # Make the background solid white
        color = Color(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        self.canvas.add(color)
        rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        self.canvas.add(rect)

        dropdown = DropDown()

        # Add the label
        label = Label(text="Report Generator", pos_hint={'x': 0, 'y': 0.20}, size_hint=(None, None))
        label.color = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
        label.size_hint = (1, 1)
        label.font_size = 26
        label.bold = True
        self.add_widget(label)

        choice = Button(text="Select Summary Report to Generate", pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .58},
                        size_hint=(0.6, 0.2))
        choice.color = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
        choice.size_hint = (0.45, 0.1)
        choice.font_size = 18
        choice.bold = False
        choice.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)
        self.add_widget(choice)

        btn1 = Button(text='Daily Report', font_size=18, size_hint_y=None, height=60)
        btn1.color = [1, 1, 1, 1]
        btn1.txt = 'Generating Daily Summary Report...'
        btn1.bind(on_release=lambda btn1: dropdown.select(btn1.txt))
        btn1.bind(on_release=lambda btn1: DailySummary())
        dropdown.add_widget(btn1)
        btn2 = Button(text='Weekly Report', font_size=18, size_hint_y=None, height=60)
        btn2.color = [1, 1, 1, 1]
        btn2.txt = 'Generating Weekly Summary Report...'
        btn2.bind(on_release=lambda btn2: dropdown.select(btn2.txt))
        btn2.bind(on_release=lambda btn2: WeeklySummary())
        dropdown.add_widget(btn2)
        dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(choice, 'text', x))


class Report(App):
    def build(self):
        Config.set('graphics', 'width', '450')
        Config.set('graphics', 'height', '250')
        return Panel()


# Application Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Report().run()
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it out and I still have the same problem as before. I have two other .py files,one is DailySummaryReport.py & the other WeeklySummaryReport.py and in the first I have a function called DairySummary() and the other has one called WeeklySummary(). I added : from DailySummaryReport import DailySummary and the same concept for the weekly one and tried to add the function names in their according spot in the if elif snipped u put, and also in the two def sections but it sadly still isnt actually running anything. What would you recommend?

Comment: You have to do the following: (1) import both files into main.py e.g. import DailySummaryReport, import WeeklySummaryReport (2) Spawn a shell process: os.system('python DailySummaryReport.py') or os.system('python WeeklySummaryReport.py'). If you are using python 3 change it to os.system('python3 DailySummaryReport.py)

Comment: I already did the imports, i did the two you said + from DailySummaryReport import DailySummary &
from WeeklySummaryReport import WeeklySummaryand, I tried to put the os thing on the top but it gives me an error.. "NameError: name 'os' is not defined" and it is not letting me download the import... can it be skipped or done differently? Also for the actual functions, DailySummary() and WeeklySummary(), where should I put those?

Comment: Actually I realized that I have already downloaded import os theres no more error showing but it still does not work and link my function properly

Comment: (1) To invoke the some function/method in your report generating Python  script, use "python-script-name.function-name" e.g. WeeklySummaryReport.some_weekly_func(). (2) To run the whole Python script, use os.system('python3 python-script.py') e.g. os.system('python3 DailySummaryReport.py'). Please refer to updated example.